# Is it possible to perform CURD operation in google cloud directly from angular app?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

i wants to develop a desktop app using angular and i need to do CURD operation for this.
so is this possible to do these operation directly from angular?
i don't want to use node or any other server side stuff.

Please tell me, if it is possible then how can i?

Comment: you can use firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing production level code this is never the a recommended way, there should always be an orchestration service/backend application. However to answer your question you can follow the below link

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/16/angular-mysql-express.

Its really difficult to suggest an approach without knowing much about your use cases. In my experience you can use either of the below approaches.

1 - Creating a VM, installing db and running the angular application
2 - Running application in app-engine and using cloud sql for managing the db.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to have some service(backend app) on GCP platform to communicate to db and to an angular app. It will also help you to implement Authorization and authentication